# Drawing a colored rectangle containing margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, margins

I want to draw a colored rectangle that contain left, top and bottom margins. Like this picture (border is not real). \Thanks :) [image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.88]
    \draw [color=blue,fill=blue] (0,-16.9) rectangle (4,5)  ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue] (current page.north west) rectangle
 ([xshift=4cm]current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}}
Hello!
\end{document}`

Comment: Excuse me, how can I add another yellow colored rectangle in center of blue rectangle? Thanks alot

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue] (current page.north west) rectangle
 ([xshift=4cm]current page.south west) node[midway,fill=yellow,minimum
 width=2cm,minimum height=5cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}
Hello!
\end{document}`, where `minimum width` and `minimum height` specify the dimensions of the yellow rectangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[blue] (current page.north west) rectangle
    ([xshift=4cm]current page.south west) node[midway,fill=yellow,minimum
    width=2cm,minimum height=5cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is true that you do not need `tikz` for *only* that but as soon as you want to have something slightly more fancy, it is very convenient, if not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a sledgehammer like TikZ to crack this nut:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%\AtPageLowerLeft{%
\color{NavyBlue!80}\rule{\dimexpr1in + \oddsidemargin}{\paperheight}}
Fiddle dee dee!

\end{document}
```

[image]